# how to access request object inside Django Form

Tags: python, django

I need to access the request object inside Django Form, to name the form fields dynamically as it looks like into the code below. The request object is currently returning None. How can i have request object inside form?

```
class PartitionAdminForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        request = kwargs.get('user', None)
        term_partition = core_utils.get_system_terms(request).get("partition")

        if self.fields.get('username'):
            self.fields['username'].label = _(f"{term_partition} Super Admin Username")
            self.fields['username'].help_text = ""
```

Comment: How are you initializing the form? If you add `request` as a parameter to the form you should "pop" it from the parameters before calling `super`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by injecting **request** object from the CreateView using function get_form_kwargs like below:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(PartitionAdminCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['request'] = self.request
    return kwargs
```

then inside the form, I have to pop the request object before initializing the form like below:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    term_partition = core_utils.get_system_terms(request).get("partition")
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    ....
    ....
```